# Sitecore 8 - How to - Custom Pop up via code + ClientPage is null

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, customdialog

I am trying to show a popup message on the content editor on click of publish . I have my handler called in the "publish:begin"event.

```
    public void PublishCatcherDialog(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        //Some custom code here including "id" declaration
        ClientPipelineArgs args = new ClientPipelineArgs();
        args.Parameters.Add("id", id);
        Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "DialogProcessor", args);
    }
```

However I see that in Sitecore 8 , Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Start gives a null exception error , so does "SheerResponse".
Most blogs out there have the code for a button click trigger that gives the appropriate command context and Sitecore.Context . How to do in in this scenario (code triggered)?

If you suggest Speak , where would I declare the .js association to this pipeline? I see the sitecore dlls still use this above code to show modal dialogs , so it cannot be completely obselete...
I feel am missing a simple inheritance somewhere that would set the context .

---

I need to trigger the alert when I click on the "Publish" button on the publish wizard dialog. It looks like a "submit" action on publishform.aspx

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMwPW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 1**

Since you need to show a popup when the user click on the publish button, you will need to override the Sitecore Publish XML UI found in the path `Website/sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs/publish`.

Copy the Publish.xml and paste it in the Override folder. Path is `Website\sitecore\shell\Override`. Note that the folder may be empty. To keep the standard create the same directory structure. Example: `Website\sitecore\shell\Override\Applications\Dialogs\publish`

Now create a class that should inherite the `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.Publish.PublishForm`

Your code will be as follows:

```
using Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.Publish;

public class PublishWizardOverride : PublishForm
{
    protected override void OnNext(object sender, EventArgs formEventArgs)
    {
        // Your code to display your popup goes here

        base.OnNext(sender, formEventArgs);
    }
}
```

Then open the copied xml file from the Override folder and change the CodeBeside with your namespace and assembly

Note: You may required to check the page on which the user is so that the popup does not appear on all Next Button clicks.

Comment: Wow ! Thanks for the detailed description above Hishaam , the code you have asked me to override is executed before the publish dialog comes up , What I need is an alert after the user has clicked the "publish button" on the wizard (image added above).

Comment: Then you need to override the Sitecore Publish UI xml file for the item and site publish

Comment: The xml path that you need to override for site publish is Publish.xml. The path is Website/sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs/publish. The item publish make use of the same xml file

Comment: I have updated the answer to match your requirement.

Comment: Thank you Hishaam , will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore event handlers run in the background so they don't have access to the UI.

If you are trying to open a custom dialog before the publish wizard dialog, you will need to override the appropriate command.  For publishing a single item, you would inherit `Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.PublishItem` and replace the `item:publish` command in the config.  For publishing the "site", you would inherit `itecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.System.Publish` and replace the `system:publish` command in the config.  You would override the execute method of the command and run your code before calling `base.Execute(context);`.

If you want to do something similar for Experience Editor mode, you would add a processor to the client-side publish pipeline.  You add a step in the core database under `/sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceEditor/Pipelines/Publish`.  You should be able to duplicate and tweak the `OpenPublishDialog` step which uses the javascript file at `/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/Pipelines/Publish/Publish.OpenPublishDialog.js`.

Comment: Thanks Ben , I have updated the ticket . I need the popup to show when I click on the "publish" button on the wizard.